# how to run bonmin from a cpp program

Tags: c++

I’ve already downloaded Bonmin-1.8.8 and compiled it. The usersmanual said that there is a cpp example in the /bonmin/examples/cppexample.I added the bin and lib to my Path but when I coded

```
g++ mybonmin.cpp -o mybonmin
```

It shows that cannot find the headfile. I want to know how can I run Bonmin with the cpp program.

Comment: You probably want to run the install step in the package too as that should put the header files somewhere sensible.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the flag to the headers:

```
g++ mybonmin.cpp -I/home/mybonmin -o mybonmin
```

[here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html) more info about it:

> -I [/path/to/header-files]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the way. But after I use the code, there are some errors like:  undefined reference to `Bonmin::BonminSetup::BonminSetup(CoinMessageHandler const*)'